# What does this for loop with undefined terms inside brackets mean in python?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, square-bracket

I have a mathematics code in python and need to convert it to java. But I can't konw how to work this:

```
#python source
sum([d**2 for d in (x - y)])
```

`x,y` are arrays and defined and have value. I have trouble with the `for` loop and the connexion with `d^2` and `d` in that loop.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual for loop surrounded by brackets is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which generates a list. This is expressed, in general, as follows:

```
[ expression( <variables> ) for <variables> in <list> ]
```

Which means your variables (here `d`) will iterate over the values in the given list (here `(x - y)`). The list returned will contain the value of the expression, evaluated for each value of `d`.

This way of writing defines the variable after it is used, so it is normal you haven't seen it defined before.

In clear, the code is equivalent to the following:

```
squares = []
for d in (x - y):
    squares.append(d**2)
sum(squares)
```

Trivially, [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) returns the sum of the list.

---

Because you say your code is doing maths and you are saying *arrays* rather than *lists*, I will suppose from here on that you mean that `x,y` are numpy arrays.

In this case, `x - y` has a meaning: item by item subtraction of the arrays.
Written as a list comprehension, it would look like: `[a - b for a,b in`[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip)`(x,y)]`

Hence a python rewrite of that code could be:

```
sum = 0
for a,b in zip(x,y):
    sum += (a - b) * (a - b)
```

Or only with numpy functions:

```
numpy.square(x - y).sum()
```